# Please specify how to implement this code between echo ' ';

Tags: php

I have using this code between  echo "";

```
<?php

    for  ($i=0; $i<$tot; $i++)
{
  $rt = date ( "d-m-Y", $y[$i] ) ;

}
  ?>
```

Please specify how to implement this code between echo "";

Comment: Implement what? What code?

Comment: @Darren: Wait until the edit is approved. OP just didn't know how to format code. *edit:* Unfortunately it's still not clear what the OP wants :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
   $output = 'for ($i=0; $i<$tot; $i++){ ';
   $output .= '$rt = date ( \'d-m-Y\', $y[$i] );';
   $output .= '}';
   echo $output;
?>
```

For readability I separated it into 4 lines, but you can see how it could easily be refactored into one echo statement.

The key idea here is that by declaring strings with `'` instead of `"`, php will not interpret the `$` signs as variables.  Additionally, in order to include single quotes within the string itself, a backslash escape character is required as in `\'d-m-Y\'`

Comment: thanks brother  you have solve  my  problem